# How to create server to use chat room realtime (SignalR) in android

Tags: android, xamarin, signalr, chat

I am beginner in android xamarin. I want to use chat room realtime using SignalR. But i dont know what is "http://10.0.2.2:8081/echo" mean in this example. Is it a server???There are something in that server - like php file, database or something else???
hope your answer, thanks :D or anybody show me how to build a group chat application, please(use socket like :http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/ or SignalR in xamarin  )

```
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using Android.App;  
using Android.OS;  
using Android.Widget;

namespace SignalR.Client.MonoDroid.Sample  
{
[Activity(Label = "SignalR.Client.MonoDroid.Sample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class DemoActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var messageListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, new List<string>());
        var messageList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Messages);
        messageList.Adapter = messageListAdapter;

        var connection = new Connection("http://10.0.2.2:8081/echo");
        connection.Received += data => 
            RunOnUiThread(() => messageListAdapter.Add(data));

        var sendMessage = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.SendMessage);
        var message = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Message);

        sendMessage.Click += delegate
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Text) && connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
            {
                connection.Send("Android: " + message.Text);

                RunOnUiThread(() => message.Text = "");
            }
        };

        connection.Start().ContinueWith(task => connection.Send("Android: connected"));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

10.0.x.x is a private subnet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). In this example then it is talking about you running some kind of server system on your computer on port 8081.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://10.0.2.2:8081/echo


10.0.2.2 is the ip of your server
8081 is the port on which server listening your request and give response on same port

echo is the automated generate respone which is given to you on every request with same request(String)

    public static class  MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
          String dstAddress;
          int dstPort;
          String response = "";
          String s;
          String red;
          String loc;
          public MyClientTask(String addr, int port,String msg){
           dstAddress = addr;
           dstPort = port;
           loc=msg;
          }
          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
           Socket socket = null;
           DataOutputStream   dataOutputStream = null;
           ObjectInputStream inputStream=null;

           try {
               SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(dstAddress,dstPort);
               socket = new Socket();
               socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
               socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
               socket.connect(socketAddress, 50000);
          //  socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
              System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
         dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         dataOutputStream.writeUTF(loc);
         ///inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
         InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(is));
         out.println(""); 
         //response = br.readLine();
         try{
                while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                    red=red+s;
              Log.i("server", ""+red);
                }
                Log.i("server", ""+red);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("Server response ", "hi"+s);
           try {

               System.out.println("Read back from server: " + response);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                 Log.i("Server response ", response+e);
            }


           } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
           }finally{
            if(socket != null){
             try {
                 dataOutputStream.flush();
                  socket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
           }
           return null;
          }
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 res=response;
              Log.i("response:", "res"+res);
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi"+res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           super.onPostExecute(result);
          }

         }



call this method to send request and get response on your desired place

public void sendtoserver(String msg){
        if(isConnectingToInternet()){

            servermsg="$loc"+","+ieminumber+","+formattedDate2+","+formattedDate1+","+formattedDate2+","+formattedDate1+","+1+","+lat1+","+"N"+","+lon1+"*";
//10.0.2.2:8081/echo
                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
                           "10.0.2.2",8081,msg);
                         myClientTask.execute();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app on an emulator and your server runs on the same pc as the emulator then the only way your client app can reach that server is using ip 10.0.2.2 as Google implemented it that way. Meanwhile your computer can have local ip like 192.168.1.12 but your app can not use that. Also the server on the pc is reachable as localhost or 127.0.0.1 by clients running on the same pc. Your app does not run on that pc. Your app runs on the emulator.